# The file specified is not a virtual disk - Error on vmx and on all snapshots

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines

I've been struggling for two days with this error now and read and executed countless solutions - but none seem to work.
I hope I find help here.

Without any warning or error my Vmaschine crashed.
When I try to open it I get the "The file specified is not a virtual disk" - Error.

I can't revert to any snapshots (Daily Snapshots are made).

Solutions I've already tried:

- Checking the vmx if it maps to the wrong vmdk - nope, everything seems to be fine.
- Removing the *.LCK folders
- Making a new VM from a vmdk (Error: "Parent of this virtual disk could not be opened")

Is there anything else I could do?
And is there anything I can provide that could help you guys and girls helping me?

Greetings and thank you for your input.

Comment: Is this happening for just one VM/disk out of many, or is it affecting all your VMs? What happens when you try and revert to a snapshot?

Comment: Hey @iwaseatenbyagrue. Thanks for your reply - in my specific case, I had to use my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in my case the only way to solve this was to go through every linked .vmdk and check if the parent one is still functioning.

I found one that was still ok from about a month ago.

There was a lot of damaged data, so I think this is a special case and should not be considered as a normal procedure.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just removed the virtual disk from the virtual VM from the  vsphere / ESXI web / whatever you use, (DON'T DELETE THE DATA),
Then re add the existing virtual disk.

Answer (score 0):

I booted up an old VM and had the same problem. Turns out I had mounted a physical SD card as an IDE drive to the VM using the "advanced" options last time the VM was in use. I didn't have an SD card in the computer anymore, so VMWare couldn't find the SD card.

Simply by going into Virtual Machine Settings and removing the mapped IDE drive I was able to fix the issue. Hope this helps someone else!